# UseState not triggering re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have a state for my orders list. On the first update everything is working fine but when an update is made on the order in the database, my order list is updated but not triggering a re-render even using <...>

```js
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.firestore()
      .collection("Orders")
      .orderBy("date", "desc")
      .limit(parseInt(limit, 10))
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        let oldOrders = orders;
        let addedOrders = []

        snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
          if (change.type === "added") {
            addedOrders.push({ ...change.doc.data(), id: change.doc.id })
          }
          if (change.type === "modified") {
            oldOrders[oldOrders.findIndex(x => x.id === change.doc.id)] = { ...change.doc.data(), id: change.doc.id }
          }
          if (change.type === "removed") {
            oldOrders.splice(oldOrders.findIndex(x => x.id === change.doc.id))
          }
        });
        if (addedOrders.length > 0) {
          oldOrders.unshift(addedOrders)
        }
        setOrders(...oldOrders);
      });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe()
    }
  }, [limit]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mutating the state.

1. `let oldOrders = orders;` does not create a copy of array. It copies reference.
2. `setOrders(...oldOrders);` makes no sense. You are spreading array as arguments but `setOrders` accepts 1 argument.
3. If your next state depends on the previous state you should use callback form of `setState`
4. You need to have `oldOrders.unshift(...addedOrders);` if you want to add multiple items not just a single array.

Your code should look somewhat like this assuming the rest of your logic is correct.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("Orders")
    .orderBy("date", "desc")
    .limit(parseInt(limit, 10))
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      // use callback form to avoid relying on stale state
      setOrders((orders) => {
        let oldOrders = [...orders]; // create new array
        let addedOrders = [];

        snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
          if (change.type === "added") {
            addedOrders.push({ ...change.doc.data(), id: change.doc.id });
          }
          if (change.type === "modified") {
            oldOrders[oldOrders.findIndex((x) => x.id === change.doc.id)] = {
              ...change.doc.data(),
              id: change.doc.id,
            };
          }
          if (change.type === "removed") {
            oldOrders.splice(
              oldOrders.findIndex((x) => x.id === change.doc.id)
            );
          }
        });
        if (addedOrders.length > 0) {
          oldOrders.unshift(...addedOrders);
        }

        return oldOrders;
      });
    });
  return () => {
    unsubscribe();
  };
}, [limit]);
```

Comment: Thank you it's working but I have to add [0] after each oldOrders otherwise I have array in array, do you know why ?

Comment: @Joris It has to be `oldOrders.unshift(...addedOrders);` if you want to add multiple items.